# How to avoid circular dependency using flask blueprints for a multiple view files

Tags: python, flask

I structured my app like the following using blueprints. The view files are 
extremely huge so I divided them into multiple files.

```sh
myapp/
    __init__.py
    admin/
        __init__.py
        views1.py
        views2.py
        views3.py
        views4.py
        static/
        templates/
    models/
        models.py
```

## myapp/**init**.py

```py
from flask import Flask
from myapp.admin import admin_bp

app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(admin_bp)
```

### myapp/admin/__init__.py

```py
from flask import Blueprint, g
from flask_login import current_user

admin_bp = Blueprint('admin', __name__, template_folder='templates')

@admin_bp.before_request
def load_logged_in_user():
    if current_user and not current_user.is_anonymous:
        user_name = current_user.user_name
        g.user = Account.get(user_name)

from . import views1, views2, views3, views4
```

### myapp/admin/view1.py

```py
from . import admin_bp

@admin_bp.route('/hello', methods=['GET'])
def hello():
    return 'Hello'
```

This is working without any specific errors. But those view files and admin/__init__.py file are importing each other (circular dependency), which should be avoided. How to structure my app using blueprints without circular dependency?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is better to use separate blueprints for each view.

Otherwise to avoid circular dependencies you can use [add_url_rule()](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Flask.add_url_rule) method. So you will have the following files:

**myapp/admin/__init__.py**

```
from flask import Blueprint, g, session, abort, request
from flask_login import current_user

admin_bp = Blueprint('admin', __name__, template_folder='templates')

@admin_bp.before_request
def load_logged_in_user():
    if current_user and not current_user.is_anonymous:
        user_name = current_user.user_name
        g.user = Account.get(user_name)

from . import views1, views2
bp.add_url_rule('/hello', view_func=views1.hello)
bp.add_url_rule('/hello2', view_func=views2.hello2)
```

**myapp/admin/view1.py**

```
def hello():
    return 'Hello'
```